# Sitefinity Inline Style is not working

Tags: sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity Stylesheet widget.When i try to apply inline style sheet inside Write CSS tab,the styles are not applied as expected

This is my code:

```
    <style>

         .menu a{
                 text-decoration: none;
                }
.....
......
    </style>
```

Could you please help me to figure out the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the tags `<style>` and `</style>`

There is already an instruction in "Write CSS tab".